# plot different groups of values under the same column in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which  looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btAp0.png)

I would like to plot it by different time period on X(T1, T2, T3), and the **mean** of likes of each time period on Y(mean of T1, mean of T2...). Can I do it without splitting columns? Many Thanks.

I'm using python 3.8.

Comment: of course, you can. Have you tried looking for other answers? Please show us what you've tried so far (it looks simple but since you asked, and assuming you have tried looking for answers, maybe it's not as easy as it seems). Also, always provide an example input (which you did) and the desired output to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupby followed by aggregation and plot will do

```
import pandas as pd # assuming you are using pan
ddict = {"No. likes": [246,435,128,333,675,342,334],
        "Time period": ["T3","T1","T2","T2","T1","T1","T3"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ddict)
```

[image]

```
df.groupby("Time period").agg({"No. likes":"mean"}).plot.line()
```

[image]